# how to check whether a function is executed

Tags: javascript, html

I have created a loader/spinner using javascript. The spinning function works till every process is over.

I have a function to stop the spinner . If any error occurs this stopping function will not be executed.

Can anybody help me to check whether the stopping function is executed or not and to alert if the spinning function doesn't exit after a time limit.

A piece of javascript code:

```
function loaderstart()
{
    var x = document.getElementById("loader");
    var xx = document.getElementById("img");
    x.style.display = "block";
    xx.style.display = "block";

    setTimeout(function(){
        if(loaderstop() != true){
            alert("check your network connection");
        }
    },10000);   
}

function loaderstop()
{
    var y = document.getElementById("loader");
    var yy = document.getElementById("img");
    y.style.display = "none";
    yy.style.display = "none";
    return true; 
}
```

Comment: add " console.log('inside loaderStop') " as 1st line inside your 2nd funciton. and check console (press F12 and search console) whether the line is present in the console. Other wise, temporarily put alert('inside loaderStop') and see whether u get an alert

Comment: Also you can shorten "if(loaderstop() != true)" to "if(!loaderstop())"

Comment: console.log is working well But some times due to the network issues second function won't work So I need to alert if loaderstop function doesn't execute

Comment: Not telling to replace your existing alert! Let that be.. :).. I was talking about adding console.log or temporarily adding alert as a debugger to check whether the function was entered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way you could do is by setting and checking a global boolean variable.

```js
var hasStopped = false;
function loaderstart()
{
var x = document.getElementById("loader");
var xx = document.getElementById("img");
x.style.display = "block";
xx.style.display = "block";
setTimeout(function(){if(!hasStopped){alert("check your network connection");}},10000);    
}

function loaderstop()
{
hasStopped = true;
var y = document.getElementById("loader");
var yy = document.getElementById("img");
y.style.display = "none";
yy.style.display = "none";
return true; 
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by if(!hasStopped) does that mean the value of hasStopped is false or "no value"

Comment: Yes. It's a Javascript shortcut (and many other languages) that basically means ```if variable == false```

Comment: ! is equivalent to NOT operator. It basically inverts the value of boolean. therefore if hasStopped = false -> !hasStopped = true

Answer (score 0):

Store timeout ID in variable and check it inside `loaderstop`:

```
var TO = 0;

function loaderstart() {
    var x = document.getElementById("loader");
    var xx = document.getElementById("img");
    x.style.display = "block";
    xx.style.display = "block";

    TO = window.setTimeout(function(){
        alert("check your network connection");
    }, 10000);    
}

function loaderstop()
{
    var y = document.getElementById("loader");
    var yy = document.getElementById("img");
    y.style.display = "none";
    yy.style.display = "none";

    if (TO) {
        window.clearTimeout(TO);
    }

    return true; 
}
```

[window.clearTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Comment: Here I guess after 10 seconds the alert appears. I need the alert only when the second function doesn't execute within a time limit

Comment: If you call `loaderstart()`, then `loaderstop()` within 10 seconds, then no alert will appear. If you call `loaderstop()` after `loaderstart()` later than 10 seconds or even never call it - alert will appear.

Comment: In case you need a different timelength - simply change the value of timeout to what you need (value is in milliseconds).